# MongoDB shell script select fields in a projection order

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongodb-query

I am trying to come up with a query that can return the fields of a document in the same order as my Projection Query.

My MongoDB **Shell query**

```
db.Tickets.find({ "ProjectID" : 70 } }, { 
    "_id" : 0, 
    "TicketProjectID" : 1, 
    "ProjectName" : 1, 
    "TicketID" : 1, 
    "Name" : 1, 
    "RequestorName" : 1, 
    "Category" : 1, 
    "Type" : 1, 
    "AssignedTo" : 1, 
    "Priority" : 1, 
    "Status" : 1, 
    "Contributors" : 1, 
    "DueDate" : 1, 
    "MonthCreated" : 1, 
    "CreatedDate" : 1 }).sort({ "CreatedDate" : -1 })
```

**Result:**

```
{
    "TicketProjectID" : 999,
    "ProjectName" : "Apps",
    "TicketID" : xxxx,
    "Name" : "Namee",
    "Status" : "Ready for QA",
    "Priority" : "3 - Normal",
    "Type" : "Bug",
    "RequestorName" : "Req Name",
    "AssignedTo" : "HaBo",
    "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2016-02-10T07:08:59.317Z"),
    "DueDate" : ISODate("2016-02-20T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "Category" : "Some Cat",
    "Contributors" : null,
    "MonthCreated" : "2016 - February"
}
```

How can I get the result in same order of my projection.

**Expected result:**

```
 {
        "TicketProjectID" : 999,
        "ProjectName" : "Apps",
        "TicketID" : xxxx,
        "Name" : "Namee",
        "RequestorName" : "Req Name",
        "Category" : "Some Cat",
        "Type" : "Bug",
        "AssignedTo" : "HaBo",
        "Priority" : "3 - Normal",
        "Status" : "Ready for QA",
        "Contributors" : null,
        "DueDate" : ISODate("2016-02-20T08:00:00.000Z"),
        "MonthCreated" : "2016 - February",
        "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2016-02-10T07:08:59.317Z")
    }
```

Also in my query how can I format my date fields to return human readable formatted dates

```
"DueDate" : ISODate("2016-02-20T08:00:00.000Z") as
"DueDate" : "2016-02-20 08:00"
```

Comment: Why does order matter? According to the JSON spec the order of the attributes is not significant.

Comment: Well I export this result to CSV, field order matters to the business team, not for IT guys though :)

Comment: If you are exporting to CSV then specify the order when you call the mongoexport command `mongoexport --db tests --collection Tickets --type=csv --query { ProjectID: 70 } --fields TicketProjectID,ProjectName,TicketID,Name --out tickets.csv`

Comment: Well actually I do that using MongoDB C# Driver. I get the results first, then Parse each field for CSV friendly value and then write to CSV. if you think I can run the above command directly on C# Driver that would be even better